# Backup and Restore in Redis cluster [Sharding] in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, backup, restore, redis-cluster

How can i take backup in redis cluster with 3 master and 1 replica per each master? I should take backup from rdb files of just masters and nodes.conf ?
How can i restore or clone (fork) my database and use backup in order to in kubernetes pod ip is not static and it changes?

Comment: I am not sure I am getting your question. So what you want to do is to backup your redid cluster and it should be restorable without regards for the IPs addresses dynamically assigned by kubernetes?

Comment: Also, how did you deploy the redis cluster? Did you use a helm chart, or the operator or did you do it manually?

Comment: I deploy with both of them. bitnami helm chart and also operator. It's not important for me to work with any of them. I want it works correctly and easy.

Comment: I want to backup from my cluster then restore that in cluster that i take backup from that or restore that in another cluster

Comment: Have a deep look into [velero](https://velero.io), and specifically [its object store providers](https://velero.io/docs/v1.8/supported-providers/#s3-compatible-object-store-providers). Basically, you set up velero on cluster A, store the data off site in an object store and all you have to do to restore is to have velero installed on the target cluster, utilizing the same object store.

Comment: I don't want to use velero. I use velero for clone or fork database but for restore i want to upload dump.rdb in s3

Comment: What? You are aware that you can do this by simply setting up and selecting another storage in your backup schedule? Dump or data file, the results are the same. If you really want to give yourself a hard time, use a sidecar.